# jQuery hide box issue

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to hide moving div when click on i'm using this code :

```
$("#image").click(function () {
  $("#image").hide();
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $("#image").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
});
```

well the box move but even when i click on it it doesn't disapear!

Comment: Could you create a JSfiddle?

Comment: the problem is hide fuction work on jsfidlle but not on my website

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors on your site?

Comment: @checkopenport give link to your webpage

Comment: Since you're `.hide()`ing `#image` you can simply use `$(this).hide()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a CSS class

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

(or `visibility:hidden;`)

...and toggle like so:

```
$("#image").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly ! but i solved proble using :onclick="this.style.visibility='hidden'"

Comment: @checkopenport you can also use jquery `.toggle()` but i find this method easier to control

Comment: to stick with jQuery, you can also use `$(this).css("visibility","hidden");`

Comment: @RUJordan true but then you should use `$(this).toggle()` see above comment

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight Done brother (f)

Comment: @checkopenport ty im kinda into the whole rep thing